# Is there a way to automate the uploading/updating of static files to Oracle Apex?

Tags: node.js, oracle-apex

I'm working on an apex project that involves a fair amount of JS and CSS, so I'm developing them on VSCode on my computer. The problem is that every time I want to change a file I have to go the static files page and upload each one separately.
Is there a post action I can call, so that I can automate the request?

Based on the submission form (for uploading files) I constructed the following code (I've masked the IP and port):

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");

upload("js", "./build/exports.min.js");

function upload(directory, filePath) {
    var req = request.post("http://0.0.0.0:800/apex/wwv_flow.accept", function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error!');
        } else {
            console.log('URL: ' + body);
        }
    });

    var form = req.form();
    form.append("P271_DIRECTORY", directory);
    form.append("P271_UPLOAD_FILE_NAME", fs.createReadStream(filePath));
    form.append("P271_FILE_CHARSET", "utf-8");
    form.append("P271_UNZIP_FILE", "Y");
    form.append("P0_FLOWPAGE", "101;1|9");
}
```

But I'm getting the error shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>404 Not found</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY><H1>Not found</H1>
The requested URL /apex/wwv_flow.accept was not found on this server</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: You may be interested in this https://github.com/OraOpenSource/apex-nitro

Comment: @Scott I'm already doing my own builder. I'm not sure how nitro would interact with my existing parsing and linting.

Comment: If you don't want to use apex-nitro (which you probably should), then you could at least learn from it and see how it does these things.